# Drupal commerce save date field product type to order

Tags: commerce

I have setup a new content type called product in Drupal 7 and I have a product reference entity multi value linking to my product type. So I can addthe sku, price I made a new field in the product type calied course dates and used the Unix date time stamp using the date module and pop up calendar.

The admin add the sku, Price and course dates which are added okay. Now the problem how can I save the course date field into the order where the sku, price smd title from the product display are stored to the order?

As the course dates expire I want to delete the dates. It says it's referenced to an order that's the reason why I want to store it into the order then delete the product variations from the product type so I don't have loads of old dates.